# Flutter Release APK size double after SDK update to 2.12 and Change Code to Null Safety

Tags: android, flutter

This is my SDK version in pubspec.yml.

**before**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

**after**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

I have to change all of my dart files from **lib** directory to Null safety.

I have 108 files in **lib** directory.

When I analyze release APK file after update, **APK size** and **Download size** is a huge difference.

**Before** update, analyzing release apk file size is like this:

[Before Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZySX.jpg)

**After** update, analyzing release apk file size is like this:

[After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQZBY.jpg)

I build release APK with

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  My app bundle is massive (and i mean massive 150+mb) since upgrading my SDK to the same as yours and migrating to null-safety

Answer (score 0):

Price of null safety. However you can split the APK:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I don't want to split the APK. I want my release APK is compatible with all ABI. I also build APK with "flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info build/app/outputs/symbols". But, that is not quite different, just some MB.